# Robocopy backup via Citrix wrong timestamps

Tags: timestamp, robocopy

I connect to a Windows 2008R2 via Citrix from a MAC. The task is to backup the HDD to my local HDD which I connected as a network drive z: in Windows.

The problem is that on my Mac the files modified date is always the current timestamp.

So far I tried

`robocopy x:\ z:\Desktop\citrix /COPY:DATSO /E /R:1 /DCOPY:T /Z`

```
robocopy x:\ z:\Desktop\citrix /MIR /Z /DCOPY:T
robocopy x:\ z:\Desktop\citrix /MIR /Z
```

I don't have admin privileges. The important things are the files but the right timestamps would be nice.

Did I execute a wrong command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to copy the files while retaining the timestamps with robocopy.  I did however found an easier solution in freefilesync. Great tool but you have to map the local drive as network drive and not use the preconfigured share citrix provides which is way slower.

You can download the program from https://www.freefilesync.org

It is available for Windows, Linux and Mac. I used it on Mac OS X 10.10 and Windows 7, 2008 R2.

Comment: I realize that you’re answering your own question — thanks for contributing to the site — but please see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511)  In particular, at a bare minimum, say where to get the software.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I wanted to post a picture but not enough reputation :)